# Form Authentication issue

Tags: asp.net

Trying to use form authentication to only allow access to a page once they have logged in via the login page. When I login and attempt the redirect it just redirects me back to the login page.

Web Login Control

```
protected void WebGenLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Verify user against active directory
        if (new AD().validate(WebGenLogin.UserName, WebGenLogin.Password))
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = WebGenLogin.UserName;
            Session.Timeout = 30;
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(WebGenLogin.UserName, WebGenLogin.RememberMeSet);
            Response.Redirect("~/WebGen/Gen/Create.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = "";
            Response.Redirect("http://thekickback.com/rickroll/rickroll.php");
        }
    }
```

Create.aspx Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/WebGen/Gen/Create.aspx" loginUrl="../Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30" />
  </authentication>
```

Comment: not the answer, but you should not store the username in the Session. Instead in your other pages use `this.User` to retrieve the username.

Comment: ok I removed it from storing the username in the session. Still original issue of course but thanks for the tip.

Comment: try running Fiddler and look for the forms authentication cookie in the response from the login page - if it is there and if the cookie persists in the next request to whatever page the user browses.

Comment: ok in fiddler I see the following. On the Login.aspx the upper cookie tab contains .ASPXUATH=2B...... the lower cookie tab contains 06....... The Create.aspx page shows upper cookie tab 06.... and lower nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code actually worked. Found it to be an issue with IIS. Needed to turn the entire folder structure into an application rather than other parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
if (new AD().validate(WebGenLogin.UserName, WebGenLogin.Password))
{
        Session["UserAuthentication"] = WebGenLogin.UserName;
        Session.Timeout = 30;
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(WebGenLogin.UserName, false);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(WebGenLogin.UserName, WebGenLogin.RememberMeSet);

        ***SNIP***
```

Comment: same result, redirected back to the login page

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of object AD() calls into, but you may not be using the default ASP.NET membership functionality.  As I recall, the ValidateUser method on the membership class has the side-effect of actually logging the user in if it returns true.

After authenticating the user, you may need to set HttpContext.User to a new IPrincipal representing the user, and then call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() before redirecting them.

Comment: All AD() does if verify the credentials against an active directory server and returns bool, nothing else is done. I have added the following which might not be correct but same results.  HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(WebGenLogin.UserName), null);

Comment: Did you call SetAuthCookie() after setting the current user?  (Chris Hardie's answer has an example but skips creating the principal).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. It had nothing to do with my code. I did however remove storing the username in the session.

What I have to do was change the root site on IIS to an application.
Authentication mode line was placed in the root with Login.aspx
Create.aspx was in another folder. I removed the authentication mode from it's Web.config and just put in the deny section and all is working correctly.